# where are the flex libraries? can i clear the cache?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Where are the [signed, cached flex libraries](http://www.onflex.org/ted/2007/06/flex-3-thursday-dramatically-smaller.php) on a windows / mac / linux system?  They don't appear to be in my browser cache... so where is adobe keeping them?

---

So, as my answer below shows, I found the files.  But can I clear the cache?  After trashing the files in windows, I don't see the files get downloaded again (with fiddler).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see Flash's cached data using the [**Website Storage Settings Panel** in the **Flash Player Setting Manager**](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html). From here you can clear data relating to a specific site, or clear all data.

This from [Adobe - Whats new in Flex 3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex3_whatsnew.html):

> The Player cache is different from the
>   browser cache in that it is maintained
>   by the Flash Player; therefore, it is
>   not cleared at the same time as the
>   browser cache, and will only store
>   items that have been signed by Adobe.

Here are a few other StackOverflow questions/answers that may have some good info:

- [SWF client side caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814855/when-an-swf-or-other-external-remote-resource-is-loaded-using-swfloader-is-the)
- [Optimizing Flex when multiple modules are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185252/optimizing-flex-when-multiple-modules-are-used)
- [Is building separate .swc allow a faster loading of the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850288/is-building-separate-swc-allow-a-faster-loading-of-the-application)

Answer (score 1):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_09.html

Platform

Location

Windows 95/98/ME/2000/XP

C:\Documents and Settings\user_name\Application Data\Adobe\Flash Player\AssetCache\

Windows Vista

C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Player\AssetCache\

Linux

/home/user_name/.adobe/Flash_Player/AssetCache/

Mac OSX

/Users/user_name/Library/Cache/Adobe/Flash Player/AssetCache/